# How do I code in actionscript the exact file location for several swf I have included for my apk?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

In Air for Android Setting's 'Include files' part, I added test1.swf and   test2.swf to the main file automatically included. Would the following be correct then:

```
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("test1.swf")
```

Or, is there any other folder I should include? Would the following be correct?

```
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("\..\..test1.swf")
```

Comment: You can simply test both methods and you will know if they work !

Comment: I can't try the second method unless I know exactly which directory do swf files go. Tried searching but couldn't find.

Comment: But if you have tested the 1st one, you will know that the second will not work because the 1st did !

Comment: nope it doesn't. should it? coz the error might be somewhere else and not the file location that's why  i need to know if i should cross  out  file location as the reason why the file ain't running

Comment: Yes it should work. I don't know what's the error that you got, but in your AS3 code, you should close the `load` function with a second bracket : `myLoader.load(new URLRequest("test1.swf"));`.

Comment: Okay, thanks. That means the error might be something else coz on my samsung phone, it just won't load the swf being called by the main swf though all works well on the desktop.(In my actual code, I have the second bracket.)

Comment: How about giving it some tries first?

Comment: I'm not sure but it might be in the applicationDirectory: myLoader.load(new URLRequest(File.applicationDirectory+"test1.swf")); (you might need a slash before test1.swf, trace the applicationDirectory string to check if there is a slash at the end already)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not in a position to test this right now on Android, but I believe included files are put in the application directory, which you can access as follows:

```
var path:String = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("test1.swf").nativePath;

myLoader.load(new URLRequest(path));
```

You can also use the shorthand url of:

```
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("app://test1.swf"));
```

---

You could also load the swf with the `FileStream` class, which gives you more control over things. That would look like this:

```
    var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("test1.swf");

    if (file.exists) {
        var swfData:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
        stream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
        stream.readBytes(swfData);
        stream.close();

        var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
        var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
        loaderContext.allowCodeImport = true;

        myLoader.loadBytes(swfData, loaderContext);
        addChild(myLoader);

    }else {
        trace("file doesn't exist");
    }
```

Comment: What error(s) are you receiving?  are you even listening for errors?  Have you tried loading the file with `FileStream` instead of using a loader?

Comment: Thank you soooo much, that did it! Yes its now running!