# Air for android ignores external swf files

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flash

I am working on some app that loads external swfs from the application directory
the problem is that some swf files get loaded correctly and others give ioerror url not found

i put the paths in an array and use a loader to load the path

```
var arr:Array = ["Games/1.swf", "Games/2.swf"];
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest(arr[0]));
```

this is just example and it is the same in loading all the files but does not work on all files.
what would be the problem?

Comment: What exact files cause an error?

Comment: The problem is simply that the files are not where they are supposed to be or maybe even not compiled with the app.

Comment: they are compiled and in the right path , i got them by directory listing in the debug

Comment: So, they are where then?  `application directory / game / 1.swf` ?

Comment: yes they exist in the path

Comment: And if you spit out the value from:  `File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("game/1.swf").nativePath` that matches up with the debug info?    and `File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("game/1.swf").exists` is `true`?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your question?

Comment: It was the capital letter in the files name

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,  whenever you load something, listen for the appropriate error events so you know what's going on:

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
```

When using mobile, you should use the `app://` shorthand as a reference to the application directory (which I assume is where your `Game` folder is.  Relative paths do not usually work.

So it should look like this:

```
var arr:Array = ["app://Games/1.swf", "app://Games/2.swf"];
```

For more information/options, you can look at [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31658745/1457439)

Comment: Your issue then, is the files are not there.   This is assuming your are getting IO Errors.  Are you listening for any error events on your loader? I've updated the answer to show what I mean.

Comment: that is what is driving me crazy, they files are there and the directory listing shows that they exist but still get ioerror while loading some files, and the weird thing now that some files which had no problem now not loading and files with ioerror are now loading, it is very weird behavior

Comment: Directory listing on your android device? or in your development environment?