# AS3 Air for Android filepath

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

Hello and thank you in advance for any help...

I have the following function that should display all the images in a sub-folder of the app storage directory:

```
public function mygallery():void
{
        var gallery:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("IMAGES/");
        var gfiles:Array = gallery.getDirectoryListing();

        var gcount:int = 0;
        gcount = gfiles.length;

        var x_counter:Number = 0;
        var y_counter:Number = 0;

        createContainer();
        callThumbs();

        function createContainer():void
        {
            container_mc = new MovieClip();
            container_mc.x = gx;
            container_mc.y = gy;
            //container_mc.width = gthumbw;
            //container_mc.height = gthumbh;
            addChild(container_mc);
        }

        function callThumbs():void
        {
            for (var j:uint = 0; j < gcount; j++)
            {
                var thumb_url = gfiles[j].nativePath;
                var thumb_loader = new Loader();
                thumb_loader.load(new URLRequest(thumb_url));
                thumb_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, thumbLoaded);

                thumb_loader.x = (gthumbw+gspw)*x_counter;
                thumb_loader.y = (gthumbh+gsph)*y_counter;
                if (x_counter+1 < gcol)
                {
                    x_counter++;
                }else
                {
                    x_counter = 0;
                    y_counter++;
                }
                //trace(gfiles[j].nativePath);
            }
        }

        function thumbLoaded(e:Event):void
        {
            var my_thumb:Loader = Loader(e.target.loader);

            my_thumb.width = gthumbw;
            my_thumb.height = gthumbh;

            container_mc.addChild(my_thumb);
        }
}
```

the gcount returns the correct number of files in the folder but for some reason the images do not display at all.

When I run this in windows it works fine, which leads me to believe that it's either a sandbox issue for Android or I'm using the file paths incorrectly.

Any advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: Well, you could start by listening for errors on the loader instead of just a complete event. See the first part of my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32077648/1457439).   Also, just a personal note, inline functions are best avoided in AS3.

Comment: hey, and thanks for the help... total noob here so please excuse my ignorance. I'm getting an error #2035 when I listen to the IOErrorEvent. How would I point to the path then? "app-storage://IMAGES/ ??

Comment: Probably, if you use `gFiles[j].url`  instead of `gFiles[j].nativePath` it will work.   The native path is more for the `File` & `FileStream` class (which might be better to use for local files anyway) and the url is more for the Loader which has sandbox restrictions with `file:` schemes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using a Loader, you should reference the `File` object's `url` property instead of the `nativePath`.  This will give you a Loader friendly `app-storage:/` scheme instead of `file:/` style reference.

First and foremost though, you should listen for errors whenever you load files:

```
thumb_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
thumb_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
```

Comment: thanks again for taking the time. I did add the event listeners you suggested. also changed the nativePath to url but still no luck.

Comment: if I add: `copymsg.text = "path: " + gallery.url + "\n" + gfiles.length + " files" + "\n" + gfiles[0].name;` I do get the following: path: app-storage:/IMAGES 1 files and the name of the file IMAG0001.JPG. However, for some reason the app shuts down and exits 5-10 sec after it displays that info, and still no thumb displayed on the stage

Comment: after fiddling with it a bit more this morning I think I found out what the issue is. Narrowed it down and put just one file in the folder. If it's a hi-res file from a camera or scanner 3+ Mb it won't display but if I put a smaller one up to 300-400kb it displays the thumbnail just fine... any idea what I can do to display the full res images?

Comment: Flash player / AIR do have a maximum resolution of image you can load. 4,095 x 4,095 total pixels I believe.   You can load it in as binary data and generate a thumbnail, but it will fairly slow on mobile.

Comment: If you change it back to us `nativePath` and try to load the smaller images, do they work?

Comment: I actually pulled a dirty trick since I don't need to load the actual files, I just display a generic file icon for each image... however it seems that I'm getting some more limitations on the php side now when I try to upload files bigger than 2Mb. And yes, to answer your question, the images are 10000x14000 px (the original ones)

Comment: Could you clarify (so I can determine the usefulness of this answer to future visitors),  is the sole issue that you were trying to load oversized images?  Or was using the native path also part of the problem?

Comment: Hey again, and sorry for taking so long to respond. I can confirm the following: .nativePath did not work at all under any circumstances (low-hi rez images). switching it to .url did work for up to 5 images at 600 dpi (medium rez). anything over (ie. 6 images at 600dpi or 1 image at 1200 dpi) crashed the app. Hope this helps

Comment: This was tested on an LG G pad II tablet with android 5.0.2, kernel 3.4.0+

Comment: Ok thanks,   it would seem this answer has answered your initial question (and if you agree it would be great if you accepted it).  Loading ultra-hi-resolution images if a pretty involved topic and I'd recommend asking a separate question for advice on how to extract a thumbnail from huge images in AS3.