# External SWF not loading when not testing in flashdevelop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

What I mean is that when I test it in flashdevelop, the External SWF loads, but when I have the main SWF outside of the project, it won't load. (eg: if I have the main SWF on my desktop, it won't work)

So, I'm trying to make a simple thing where when I click a button, it loads an External SWF.

Here's the function for loading the External SWF:

```
    public function loadPart(part:String)
    {
        if (loader.numChildren > 0)
            loader.removeChildren(0);
        stage.addChild(loader);
        trace(part)
        loader.load(new URLRequest("../src/"+part+".swf"));
        stage.addChild(medButton)
        stage.addChild(slowButton)
        stage.addChild(fastButton)
    }
```

part being the name of the SWF

This works fine when I test in flashdevelop, but if I clone the SWF in the bin folder of the project folder to the desktop, it won't work. It also works if I just open the SWF in the bin folder.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: first and foremost, you should listen for errors when you load files.  For an example, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32077648/1457439).  This can help you narrow down what the problem is.   Trace/Log/Display any IO or Security errors and see what is actually happening.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: Nope, I've also given up and don't really mind anymore.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, you should listen for errors whenever you load files as a best practice.

You can do that by doing the following:

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);

function ioErrorHandler(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
    //file not found, the event (e) will tell you the path it was trying to load and other details
    trace(e);
    //alert the user there was a problem
}

function securityErrorHandler(e:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
    //file was not allowed to load, sandbox issue
    trace(e);
    //alert the user there a problem
}
```

---

My best guess with the information provided, is that you are getting an IOError.

You are loading a file that is in a sibling directory to your program, so it would seem you have a structure resembling this:

```
  -> YOUR APPLICATION DIRECTORY
     -> BIN
         -> yourProgram.swf

     -> SRC
         -> yourExternalSwfAsset.swf
```

If you copied the entire bin folder to your desktop and then ran `yourProgram.swf`, in order for the external swf to load, there would have to be a `src` folder on the desktop as well (with the external swf file in it).  If you haven't copied that src folder to the desktop, then this is indeed your issue.

If you copied just `yourProgram.swf` directly to the desktop, then the SRC folder would have to be in the parent directory of the desktop.

At any rate (and even if this isn't your issue in the end), you should keep all the local assets needed for your program inside the `bin` folder (eg move your src folder and any other run-time loaded content into the bin folder and take off the "../" part of your URL path).

The whole purpose of `bin` folders is to contain everything needed for a compiled program to run.   If you end up packaging your app to make an AIR file or other package, anything outside of the bin folder will not be included in the packaged.

Comment: Still not working, even if I do the things you said (put everything inside bin, put the main swf and SRC folder into desktop etc)

Comment: What error are you getting and what is the details of that error?

Comment: I don't get any pop error or anything. Just a blank screen where the SWF should be

Comment: Are listening for errors though or running it through the debug flash player?

Comment: [The flash debug player?](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html)

Comment: Yes that one,  you can use the projector one.  It will show you unhandled errors.  If you're handling errors (like my example), you'll need to either take that out, or throw the error in the handler function: `throw e;`

Comment: Will they also not appear if I'm using a old flash player version? I found out I use 19.0 when testing, and 10.0 when not

Comment: I opened it from the desktop with the debug flash player and got the normal URL not found error. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, so you are getting an IOError,  does it show you the URL of the file it failed to load?  If so, is that path correct and actually point to the file you're trying to load?

Comment: Doesn't show any path. Just Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.